# Improve performance on image classification model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm currently working on an image classification model for identifying 101 different types of food, utilizing a dataset comprised of 101.000 images (1000 per class).
I am developing this classificator in **Google Colab** and utilizing **Tensorflow 2.4.1**.

In order to increase performance, I added `ds.cache()` and `ds.prefetch()` statements to my dataset, but by doing this, **colab** quickly runs out of RAM during the first training epoch and the process is killed.

**Performance Tuning**

```
AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE
train_ds = train_ds.cache().shuffle(1000).prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
```

I also defined a normalization layer that simplifies the RGB channel of my images to a [0,1] vector:

```
normalization_layer = layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255)

normalized_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x, y: (normalization_layer(x), y))
image_batch, labels_batch = next(iter(normalized_ds))
first_image = image_batch[0]
# Notice the pixels values are now in `[0,1]`.
print(np.min(first_image), np.max(first_image))
```

However, by removing the `ds.cache()` and `ds.prefetch()` functions from the dataset, training becomes very slow:

`Epoch 1/2 86/2525 [>.............................] - ETA: 6:37 - loss: 4.6159 - accuracy: 0.0099`

**Below** is my model specification and summary, I am using the **adam optimizer** and a **Sparse Categorical Crossentropy** loss function.

```
num_classes = 101

model = Sequential([
  layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255, input_shape=(img_height, img_width, 3)),
  layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Flatten(),
  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')
])
```

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
rescaling_3 (Rescaling)      (None, 224, 224, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 224, 224, 16)      448       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 112, 112, 16)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 112, 112, 32)      4640      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_4 (MaxPooling2 (None, 56, 56, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 56, 56, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_5 (MaxPooling2 (None, 28, 28, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 50176)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 128)               6422656   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 101)               13029     
=================================================================
Total params: 6,459,269
Trainable params: 6,459,269
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

What are some alternatives to caching and prefetching I can implement to increase the training performance?

Comment: That network seems too shallow for 101 classes.

Comment: Following sholderbach's suggestion, I have added a few more convolutional layers, having 5 in total now.

Answer (score 0):

### Caching

`tf.data.Dataset.cache` will try to load the whole epoch worth of data into memory if no cache file is specified. Maybe that is the primary culprit for your out-of-memory situation. `prefetch` caches just a few batches.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#cache

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#prefetch

### Model performance

Generally you are spending most of your network compute on `dense2` as the incoming dimension from `flatten` is quite large. This seems inefficient. More aggressive downsampling before that should increase the model throughput. You could compensate for the reduction in parameters/expressive power by doing this with more convolutional layers. Convolutions with their inductive bias for images also help to generalize better than dense layers.

### other considerations

1. check your preprocessing pipeline. Are you rescaling twice? If the step is faster on the dataset do it there.
2. Do you run on the Colab GPU instance?
3. Maybe consider using a model pretrained on e.g. ImageNet and just do transfer learning for your specific task. This should yield good results quicker than training a complete model from scratch, even if the pretrained model itself is much larger than a model that you could reasonably train from scratch. (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning)

Comment: My performance tuning would be modified to `train_ds = train_ds.shuffle(1000).prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)`, correct?

Comment: Check if that helps!

Comment: Also make sure to use `ds.batch` to create reasonably sized minibatches. From your code it looks like you try to run one image at a time through the network. This wouldn't leverage the parallel computation efficiently and has negative effects on training stability.

Comment: Added `ds.batch` and fixed the issue of double rescaling on my dataset. As for the pretrained model, I unfortunately cannot do that because this is part of a school assignment that demands a model made from scratch, good suggestions though!
Edit : I will apply some more changes, such as adding a few more convolutional layers and try out the training process, will update with results.